# Unable to eliminate Pacific gap

Tags: modis-reprojection-tool

I am trying to project APJ specific meridian on -180, under WGS84/PDC Mercator always produces gap as attached.

Can you help explain how to manage an overlapped projection?

[image]

Comment: Can you please give more details such as the platform you are using?